# How to list all PDFs from external storage on Android 11

Tags: android

I'm trying to list all pdfs from external storage by bellow code,
it works on Android <= 10 but not Android 11 due to "Scoped storage".

```
 val pdfMineType = 
     MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
 val queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
 val selection += MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE
                            + "='"
                            + pdfMineType + "'"
 val projection = arrayOf(
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE
                )
 var sortQuery = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC"
 cursor = ctx.contentResolver.query(
                        queryUri,
                        projection,
                        selection,
                        null,
                        sortQuery
                    )
```

Anyone know how to make it works on Android 11, please help me..

Comment: Please show the value of used variables.

Comment: Are you running app on Android 11 and targeting the build for Android 10?

Comment: @Jordan both does not work(targeting Android 10 and 11)
Also Play Store will require target sdk 30 as of August 2021

Comment: For a temporary fix for now you can target build for API 10 and use the flag `requestLegacyExternalStorage`. As per official Android docs:
This flag allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files. After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag.

Comment: @Jordan I know but Play Store will require target sdk 30 as of August 2021

Comment: Define pdfMineType too.

Comment: @HaiNguyen any source of this news: "Play Store will require target sdk 30 as of August 2021"?

Comment: @Jordan https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

Comment: What have you tried with changing your variables a bit? For instance without .DATA? And what do you get instead? Tell what your code does so we dont have to try it to find out

Comment: @blackapps I removed .DATA but still no pdfs

Comment: You should experment more.